# Browser Freezes/Hangs while running Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've search over the net and still couldn't find a solution for my problem. Every time when I run my function, my browser hangs or freezes until the function getwidgets() is completely loading. My function is as below.

```
var offset = -1;
var uniqueRandoms = [];
var numRandoms = 6;
function makeUniqueRandom() {
    // refill the array if needed
    if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numRandoms; i++) {
            uniqueRandoms.push(i);
        }
    }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
    var val = uniqueRandoms[index];

    // now remove that value from the array
    uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);
    return val;
}

function getwidgets(){
    $('#loading_message').fadeIn(100);
    offset = offset + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(i){
                var rand_no = makeUniqueRandom();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../ajax/widgets.php",
                    data: "offset="+offset+"&select="+rand_no,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(html){
                        var firstcol = $('#first_column').outerHeight();
                        var secondcol = $('#second_column').outerHeight();
                        var thirdcol = $('#third_column').outerHeight();
                        if(firstcol<secondcol && firstcol<thirdcol)
                            $('#first_column').append(html).fadeIn(300);
                        else if(secondcol<thirdcol && secondcol<firstcol)
                            $('#second_column').append(html).fadeIn(300);
                        else
                            $('#third_column').append(html).fadeIn(300);
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $('#loading_message').fadeOut(300);
                    }
                });
            }, 0)
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Every time when I run the function getwidgets(), my browsers would hangs until it completely loading. How do I know this? Notice the $('#loading_message').fadeIn(100)? This message appears when the browser hangs or freezes. And then it disappears when ajax finishes loading. How can I make the Ajax load in the background?

My widgets.php is something like this.... Just an example, you get the idea....

```
<?
require('../inc/config.php');
$offset = $_POST['offset'];
$select = $_POST['select'];
?>

<? if($select == 0 && $offset % 2 == 0){ ?>
<?  $sql_stmt = "SELECT id, name, address, address_2, city, postcode, date_created FROM locations ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET ".$offset."";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $sql_stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    if($row){
?>
    <div id="new_hotspot" class="count_div">
        Return data back to main...
    </div>
<? }} else if($select == 1){ ?>
some divs here......
<? } ?>
```

My php would return a whole divs with selected data from the database.. I suspect that my data is too huge and it makes it load slowly.

But how can I let it loads in the background?

Comment: The message `$('#loading_message').fadeIn(100)` will appear when you call the function `getWidgets`. You're then waiting for the AJAX response to come back. The default settings for `$.ajax` is to be asynchronous, so it shouldn't hang on the actual ajax call - Personally, I would rule out ajax not loading in the background (it probably is)... There's a lot of things that can be happening to cause a slow response. Maybe your SQL query is slow? Have you benchmarked the response time? Maybe your response is too large (as you said). Unfortunately, it's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, I suspect my SQL query might be slow but I need that query to get the data I want. How come facebook and other websites could make the loading bar appears but then not hang the browser... How can I achieve what they achieve? They have fast servers?

Comment: Sorry, I think it depends on what you mean by hang. When you say hang, do you mean your JavaScript is blocking? Or, do you mean nothing happens after you make the $.ajax request until the response comes back?

Comment: I'm not able to click elsewhere or switch to a different tab. The page also hangs as I can't click on other links or menu on that page.

Comment: Ah, I got you. One thing you may want to consider is breaking up the AJAX calls in your for loop so that the subsequent one is called AFTER the response comes back for the previous one.